# root can log into centOS and use xshell, but other users can't

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

Details are as follows:

```
[root@hadoop102 hadoop]# ssh atguitu@hadoop103
atguitu@hadoop103's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
atguitu@hadoop103's password:
```

I want log into centOS and use Xshell with other users. I've tried a lot of methods and they haven't worked. So I don't know if there are any permissions that need to be set?

Comment: are other users *allowed* to log in, by the SSH server? Is the SSH server *aware* of these other users, or is it possibly missing, for example, the PAM modules to even know about some user defined by some network domain controller?

Comment: how to know other users is allowed? I used to add command of AllowUsers to the file of /etc/ssh/sshd_config, as follow,
AllowUsers:root atguigu
but it's don't work

Comment: Have you created the user accounts on the system itself? For example, if you log on to hadoop103, does `getent passwd atguitu` return something or nothing?

Comment: Why are you changing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? Under normal circumstances you should never need to change that file

Comment: used getent passwd atguigu,I get like this,
[atguigu@hadoop102 hadoop]$ getent passwd atguigu
atguigu:x:1000:1000::/home/atguigu:/bin/bash

Comment: I solved it,maybe I didn't passwd atguigu